# Forecasting with VARs: Merge differenced forecast with original data in levels

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, data-transformation, vector-autoregression

I am using R and am trying to figure out how to merge some forecasts I've done via the `vars` package, back to my original `xts` data, which is in levels.

In previous work, I would have used only level data and used `rbind` to merge the old data with the forecasts, e.g.:

```
series <- rbind(orig, fcst)
```

However, the new forecasts I have are in differences, and I'm kind of at a loss as to how to merge the differenced data with the original data in levels. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the last observed value $y_t$ and a foreast for the differenced series $\widehat{\Delta y}_{t+1} = \hat y_{t+1} - y_t $, then clearly the forecast of $y_{t+1}$ is $\hat y_{t+1} := y_t + \widehat{\Delta y}_{t+1}$.

Similarly, $\hat y_{t+2} := y_t + \widehat{\Delta y}_{t+1} + \widehat{\Delta y}_{t+2}$ and so on until $\hat y_{t+h} := y_t + \sum_{i=1}^h \widehat{\Delta y}_{t+i}$.

Thus use cumulative sums of the forecasts for the first differences added to the initial value $y_t$ to obtain forecasts for levels of $y_t$.

The R implementation would be `apply(rbind(orig,fcst),2,cumsum)`.